# how to force input[type=range] to the right css

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, scss-mixins

pls how can i force the input[type=range] to move to the right corner relative to the page or video element, the input[type=range] is the video control, i tried everything but the input[type=range] just keeps staying in one place, Heres my code

call.page.scss page

```
ion-content{
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    display:block;
}
.row{
    position: relative; 
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
video{        
    background-color: transparent;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    object-fit:fill;
}
.range {
    position: absolute; 
    width:5%; 
    height: 50%;
    top:30% !important;
    right:2% !important;  
    z-index:20 !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg)
}
.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #555;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#4ddbff), to(#0cf));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #4ddbff, #0cf);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #4ddbff, #0cf);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #4ddbff, #0cf);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #4ddbff, #0cf)
}
.range:focus {
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important
}
```

Heres the call.page.html page

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="row"> 
        <ion-button *ngIf="record" (click)="startRecording()"> Record </ion-button>
        <ion-button *ngIf="stop" (click)="stopRecording()"> Stop</ion-button>
        <ion-button *ngIf="download" (click)="DownloadAm()"> Download</ion-button>
        <ion-button (click)="PauseAm()"> Pause</ion-button>
        <ion-button (click)="sendToServer()"> sendToServer</ion-button>
        <video id="video" playsinline></video>
        <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" [value]="volume" (change)="changeVolume($event.target.value)">
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Please what am i doing wrong, i need help

Comment: how you set the relation between video and input range?

Comment: i don't understand